# Cakephp 3 belongsToMany subquery searching

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have a products table that belongsToMany Tags and Categories. The Tags and Categories also belongsToMany products.

I am trying to implement a searching functionality that will include any products where the search parameters match tagged products, categorized products, and any product's title or description.

This is what I have in my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->paginate = [
        'sortWhitelist' => [
            'Products.title',
            'Products.msrp',
            'Products.sale_price',
        ],
        'limit'   => 48,
        'order'   => ['Products.title' => 'asc']
    ];
    $products = $this->Products->find();
    if ($search = $this->request->query('search')) {
        $matchingCategories = $this->Products->find()->matching('Categories', function ($q) use ($search) {
            return $q->where(['Categories.name LIKE' => "%$search%"]);
        });
        $matchingTags = $this->Products->find()->matching('Tags', function ($q) use ($search) {
            return $q->where(['Tags.name LIKE' => "%$search%"]);
        });
        $products
            ->where(['Products.title LIKE' => "%$search%"])
            ->orWhere(['Products.description LIKE' => "%$search%"])
            ->orWhere(['Products.id IN' => $matchingCategories])
            ->orWhere(['Products.id IN' => $matchingTags]);
    }

    $this->set('products', $this->paginate($products));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['products']);
}
```

You can kind of see what I am trying to accomplish here, but it obviously doesn't work. I can get any 1 part of the equation to work, meaning I can either get products with matching categories, or products with matching tags, or products with matches in their title or descriptions, but I can't get all products where the search fits in any of these parts.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all I had to do was select just the id field in the subqueries like this:

```
$matchingCategories = $this->Products->find()->select(['Products.id'])->matching('Categories', function ($q) use ($search) {
    return $q->where(['Categories.name LIKE' => "%$search%"]);
});
```

NOTE: I am open to suggestions for improvement.

Comment: Well, there aren't too many options here... another one would be to left join `Categories` and `Tags` and add the `LIKE` conditions on `Products` level. May give you better performance, may give you worse, as pretty much always with SQL, its "it depends". A slightly different option would be to use `EXISTS` instead of `IN` - again, performance may be better, may be worse.

Comment: @ndm Thank you for the comment. I will fiddle with it to see if I can get better performance.